# Is concatenating classes good practice?

Tags: css, css-selectors, design-patterns, code-maintainability

Why do I see `.closed-dialogue` and `.open-dialogue` so often in commonly-used libraries, instead of `.closed.dialogue` and `.open.dialogue`?

### the problem with a single class per element

To format all dialogues with the first approach, you would already need two classes in the selector.

Each time you add another difference, f.e. some colour, you would multiply the number of classes in the selector: `.warning-dialogue-closed, .error-dialogue-closed, .warning-dialogue-open, .error-dialogue-open`.

Now how can that be good practice? This is hardly maintainable!

You couldn't even separate your code in modules, since the basic selector for dialogues needs to know all dialogues that exist!

### several classes per element solve this

By concatenating several classes, the code would be way shorter, more maintainable and easier to read:

`.dialogue` formats all dialogues, no matter how many different you have.

`.error.dialogue` and `.warning.dialogue` would add changes for either flavour. `.open.dialogue` and `.closed.dialogue` would take care of the other difference.

You even could have another isolated module that defines *big* and *small* dialogues, and the basic module doesn't even have to know about it.

**So why have I never seen this?**

Comment: If you've never seen it, you've not been looking hard enough. It's not that uncommon a practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that it's more likely to conflict with other classes.

If the page itself has some other unrelated `open` class, `class="open dialog"` will pick up rules for that class and get messed up.

This is why libraries like jQuery UI tend to prefix all of their classes with a unique value.

Comment: So they're using as long class names as possible and make it nearly impossible to keep track of them so that nobody incidentally overwrites them. Nice.